# AudioQueue callback and inUserData pointer lifetime

Tags: objective-c, callback, core-audio

I've been working on an application in Objective-C that uses `AudioQueueNewOutput`. I've got experience with other sound libraries so the callback mechanism is familiar. However, one issue I've had is with the `inUserData` pointer. When you call `AudioQueueStop`, even with immediate set true, the callback can run again. This makes it inappropriate to deallocate whatever is in the user pointer at the same time as calling `AudioQueueStop`.

Is this the purpose of `kAudioQueueProperty_IsRunning`? Does the callback of that listener guarantee that the queue callback will not be called again and that the user pointer is safe to be deallocated?

If that is not the correct mechanism, then it's hard for me to think of what could be. The callback could try to synchronize how many buffers it thinks are left after `AudioQueueStop` has been called, but that seems fragile. I would like to avoid hacks like deallocating after so many seconds or leaking memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that you can use property listeners to do this safely. In particular, `kAudioQueueProperty_IsRunning`. Your object can keep a reference of itself and then `nil` it when the queue stops running.

As an example,

```
@interface Foo : NSObject
@end

@implementation Foo {
  AudioQueueRef queue;
  Foo *inUse;
}

static void listener_callback(void *user_data, AudioQueueRef queue,
                              AudioQueuePropertyID prop) {
  Foo *p = (__bridge id)user_data;
  UInt32 res;
  UInt32 resSize = sizeof(res);
  AudioQueueGetProperty(queue, kAudioQueueProperty_IsRunning, &res, &resSize);
  if (resSize == sizeof(UInt32) && res == 0) {
    p->inUse = nil;
  }
}

- (id)init {
  // ... set up self and audio queue
  // create some kind of playback callback
  inUse = self;
  AudioQueueAddPropertyListener(queue, kAudioQueueProperty_IsRunning,
                                listener_callback,
                                (__bridge void *_Nullable)self);
  AudioQueueStart(queue, NULL);
  return self;
}
@end
```

The property listener callback is only called when the queue starts and stops. If `AudioQueueGetProperty` yields 0 for this property, then the callback will not be called again and you are safe to deallocate.

Answer (score 2):

According to Apple, memory management of any kind should not be done inside an Audio context callback.  All memory of interest to the callback should be pre-allocated or retained outside the callback, before starting the Audio Unit or Queue.  Thus the retain state should be of little interest inside any audio callback.

To be maximally cautious, I don't deallocate audio buffers until app termination (if that is ever called).  Audio buffers are usually pretty small anyway, compared to the app's total memory footprint.  Rather than leaking, I just leave them in a pool until needed again (if ever).

If you really want to deallocate, since you know the sample rate and how big your buffers are, you can estimate how long it will take for all your live buffers to empty.  Quadruple that (to account for potential OS double buffering) and the estimate should be reasonably safe.

Comment: That’s exactly how I do it.  It always seems hacky, but it’s a pragmatic solution to the problem.  Just free the render memory in a dispatch_after block from dealloc.

Comment: To be clear, it's not just the buffers I'm hoping to deallocate, though I want to deallocate those too. In my case, the user pointer given to the callback wants to deallocate but it can't because it's still possibly in use by the callback. So the memory usage there is somewhat more sizeable.